# Query Builder for Laravel to count all 25 to 35 years old that are single

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

Here are the columns of my member_profiles table:

id
last_name
first_name
birthday
civil_status

Civil status values are "single", "married", and "divorced".

This table already have thousands of entries. 
I want to count all members that are 25 to 27 years old that are single.

I could start off with something like this, but don't know how to continue to match it up with specific age range

`$members = MemberProfile::where('civil_status', 'single')->count();`

Comment: sounds great, so perhaps try something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
$count = DB::table('member_profiles')
         ->select(DB::raw('floor(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),birthday) /365) as age') ,'civil_status')
         ->where('civil_status','single')
         ->where('age','>',25)
         ->where('age','<',35)
         ->count();
```

Here `floor` funtion is for rounding down in case of decimal value. Since `month_between` is not recognized in sql you can use `DATEDIFF()` which gives you in terms of days and divide it by 365 to get age value.

Hope, you understand.

Comment: oh, nice one @sagar gautam. I will try that.What do I use if instead of putting in today's date manually, it's something that will reference to "today's date"

Comment: you can use `CURDATE()` function of MySQL.

Comment: @RodneyZanoria I've updated take a moment to view it.

Comment: Sagar Gautam, I've tried your code and it gives me "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'age' in 'where clause'"

Comment: @RodneyZanoria Inside raw query i've defined `as age` so column should be there I think

Comment: @RodneyZanoria Can you add output of `$count = DB::table('member_profiles')
         ->select(DB::raw('floor(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),birthday) /365) as age') ,'civil_status')
         ->where('civil_status','single')->get();`

Comment: @Saugar Gautam yes its giving me the list. The last code you sent is working. What to do next

Comment: @RodneyZanoria Can you add the output of last code ?

Comment: [{"age":22,"civil_status":"Single"},{"age":24,"civil_status":"Single"},{"age":16,"civil_status":"Single"} and so on

Comment: @RodneyZanoria 
"age" is there so my answer should work I wonder why ? :D Age values are correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use carbon and `whereBetween`

```
  use Carbon\Carbon;
  Class {
  .......
  .......
  $today = Carbon::now();
  //$today = Carbon::createFromDate(2017, 7, 2);//to make manually
  $sub25 = $today->subYears(25);
  $today = Carbon::now();
  //$today = Carbon::createFromDate(2017, 7, 2);//to make manually
  $sub35 = $today->subYears(35);


  $members = MemberProfile::where('civil_status', 'single')
  ->whereBetween("birthday",[$sub25,$sub35])
  ->count();
```

Comment: do you think this will work ? `$sub35` value will be 25+35 = 60 years before the current day so please improve your answer.

Comment: Hi @Rishi I have tried your response and it's not working. Reason I see is that in ->whereBetween("birthday",[$sub25,$sub35]), birthday column in my table is in format of YYYY-MM-DD and not in years. How to resolve